HIt "PolarDB time zone set to Asia/Tokyo invalid" error
I am using PolarDB 5.7. Try to set time zone to "Asia/Tokyo", but the following error: PolarDB time zone set to Asia/Tokyo invalid. It seems works fine on PolarDB 8.0.
Further more, I can set time zone to "Asia/Tokyo" in vanilla MySQL though.
